# keep a separate file with php class and pass variable to it

Tags: php, oop, class

I want to keep a class separately like joomla configuration.php file.So i can create a php page which contain a class.

Comment: Google is the best answer

Comment: It's not in google.I was find it in all google servers

Comment: The PHP Documentation is even better than Google - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: create an object of the class and use it to set an attribute

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut i want to fill the variable data...How i do it remortly ?

Comment: What do you mean remotely? You don't seem to have done much research yourself; you don't seem to be able to explain what you want - please clarify exactly what you are after

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/34356191.jpg

Comment: i want to keep that class for later use ?

Comment: Like joomla configuration.php

Comment: You really aren't explaining what you want at all

Comment: Your question makes it clear that you have no idea what object oriented programming is. That is okay, but you should ask yourself if you want to use it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the class in one file, then include it using any of these options:

[Includes:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/class.php');
```

[Require:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/class.php');
```

[Require Once:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/class.php');
```

Or you can target the class with ajax or a form:

```
/includes/class.php?var=input
```

In the class include you would use:

```
if(!empty($_GET['var'])){
   //Do some check here for validation
   //let's say I'm expecting a number
   if(is_numeric($_GET['var'])){
     $var = $_GET['var'];
   }
}
```

Then use the var in your class.